# @JsonProperty sets the value to null

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

This is a simple GET from a resource. All returned entries (from the databaes) have values.

After annotating a field like this:

```
@JsonProperty("title")
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

I'm getting a null value on that certain field in the JSON response

```
{
    "title" : null
}
```

If I remove the annotation

```
private String name;
```

It returns the correct value.

```
{
    "name" : "This is a test"
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: i want ask you question ..when you remove `@JsonProperty` why your output like  `"title":"This is a test"`? ..it should be  `"name":"This is a test"`

Comment: Sorry, yes, it will be "name"

Comment: don't know what you doing wrong here ...but as per your code everything right..

Comment: but you really want different name in JSON other name your property name?

Comment: check your setter method of `name` property . ..

Comment: I've added the setter and getter above. Yup, I agree the code looks right. But it is still outputting incorrect. I put this up for another eyes to see what I've might missed.

Comment: I don't really need a different name. I'm only testing what JsonProperty annotation is.

Comment: There's too little information in your question. If you really want an answer for this please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, that's how simple it is. Can't elaborate it more.

Comment: Anyway, I did a mvn clean and run it again. Issue is now gone.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lombok for the POJO, just define a setter for name. Like:

```
public void setName(String name){
  this.name = name ;
}
```

Comment: This is just a simple POJO. Yes, I have the same setter and getter.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but in some weird way it solves my problem.

I just did clean and run the app again. Maybe there was a cached class.

```
mvn clean
mvn spring-boot:run
```